# How do movies typically do corpses, with real people or manikins?

Tags: props, costume

What is the usual practice for displaying random corpses in movies (not corpses of principal characters)? Is the usual practice to use extras made up to look like corpses or is it possible to buy or rent extremely life-like (or dead-like) manikins?

For example, early in the movie "Sicario" there is a scene in which the FBI opens up the walls of a house and finds dozens of corpses in plastic bags in the walls. Would those be real people or manikins?

Comment: I could be incorrect - but the corpses in Sicario are wrapped in plastic and badly treated.  It seems that applying that as make-up and using people who might breathe and move would be harder than just using inanimate material of some sort.  That's a very specific example where I would be astonished if real people were used.

Comment: I was listening to a podcast interviewing one of the producers of LOST not too long ago - it was apparently cheaper to pay actors to play corpses on the beach rather than hire mannequins. But it probably depends on the production, the number needed, and the "freshness".

Comment: I couldn't put a percentage on it. I've seen [& been] both. Dummies are often used if there's any danger or rough treatment anticipated. Real people if close-ups are needed & the 'corpse' isn't *too* badly mangled. Sometimes even dead main characters are played by live other people. I was 'dead' in Jack Ryan, whilst the identically made-up real actor was otherwise engaged. He played his own corpse for shots the audience would be able to spot the difference. [I can flesh this out - so to speak - into an answer if no-one else has any firm stats].

Answer (score 2):

Corpses can be presented in movies in multiple different ways:

1. There can be corpses acted by real people, but these are usually when there is a close-up of the face, or the body isn't injured or maimed anywhere, even if they are bloody makeup can be used.
2. Like you said, manikins, but these would probably only be used if the corpses are out of sight, or extremely far away so avid viewers wouldn't notice.
3. The last way would be to use CGI. This can be used to create a 3D picture of a corpse, sometimes with the distinct or even accurate facial features of the actor or person portraying the dead person. See below for an example from *Sicario*. This method would probably be used for high-budget movies and films where they cannot get actors to portray corpses in difficult positions.

[image: Example from Sicario.]

Of course, most films produce outstandingly good visual effects using the combination of the methods above and more.